# Align text to the right, overflowing to the left

Tags: html, css

*Note: This question is not answered in the above linked question, nor is it a duplicate. This question addresses the problem with the ordering of special characters when using `text-direction: rtl`, which it turns out can be solved with the `unicode-bidi: bidi-override` as pointed out by @Serlite below.*

I have a div containing some text that I'd like to overflow to the left, not to the right.

For example, if the div contains all letters of the alphabet, the default behaviour is as follows:

[image: Image 1]

I, however, want the contents of the div to be displayed like this:

[image: Image 2]

Using `direction: rtl` in the styles for that div works fine, and achieves this effect perfectly for the above example, as well as if the contents contains just numbers (or a mix of alphanumeric characters) as shown below.

Standard behaviour:

[image: Image 3]

Behaviour after setting `direction: rtl`:

[image: Image 4]

The problem occurs when special characters are entered into the div, such as * and #.

Setting the string `*#0123456789` as the div contents causes the following to be displayed:

[image: Image 5]

*Note the `*` moving from the start of the string to the end.*

It's difficult to show the problem with just images, so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/) is a quick jsfiddle to better demonstrate it.

In general, it seems like weird things happen when setting the `direction` property, and so I'm guessing it's probably not the way to go.

Is there a way I can force the last characters to always be visible while the first characters overflow to the left?

Comment: Is your div `contenteditable` and content of it changable or is constant?

Comment: What about with `text-align: right` ? Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/3/

Comment: please tellme you don't mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/4/

Comment: @Mohammad No, just a regular ol' div with static content.

Comment: @PeterDarmis @VincentG that doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. If you fill the inputs in your example so that they overflow, you'll see that `text-align: right;` doesn't solve the issue. See my 2nd and 4th images above for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: "In general, it seems like weird things happen when setting the direction property, and so I'm guessing it's probably not the way to go." Different punctuation symbols behave differently in different writing modes. This is perfectly normal behavior. But for your purposes, direction is indeed not the way to go.

Comment: @dippas I think it does not solve the problem. The OP question is how to avoid (or solve) that the `*` does not move to right.

Comment: @error404 You're correct, the accepted answer doesn't solve the issue, however a later answer suggesting using a wrapper div to take care of clipping the overflowing text on the left might actually do the trick. I'd considered that previously but it seemed like a bit of a hacky way to do it, but if there's no simpler way then that will be the way I go.

Comment: Are you fine using JS?

Comment: @JacobGray If there's a clean way to do it with JS then that's fine

Comment: @joshfarrant https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/5/ is that clean enough?

Comment: There is a funny way in css to let overflow disseapear at left ... https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/7/

Comment: @GCyrillus Think that's going to be similar to the way I solve it, and as in dippas's linked duplicate above.

Comment: i see, did not noticed the answers of Abe out there

Comment: Well, maybe there is a less tricky way with text-indent : https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/8/ (also as a snippet in answer below) + should work in any language ...

Comment: It is annoying that overflow-X: hidden and text-align: right don't do the trick. Does anyone know why browsers handle it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unexpected reordering you're observing is due to an algorithm used for determining the ordering of bi-directional text. I won't go into details on how the ordering is exactly determined, but basically characters are classified by strong, weak, and neutral directionality, which is used to order them in a string.

Your string "*#02468" consists only of a mix of characters with weak or neutral directionality, meaning their ordering may be unexpected without the context of a strongly directional character (like Arabic text, which reads right-to-left). Depending on the characters you use, they may seem to contradict the specified `direction`.

To avoid this behaviour you're encountering, you can use the [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) property to override the algorithm, and rely strictly on the specified direction:

```
#rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/6/).

You can also read up a bit more on the [logical ordering of this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text), if you're interested. It's a bit too complex to go into detail about.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

*Note: If you don't want the characters in your string reversed, this won't work for you. In that case, go with an approach that doesn't use the `direction` property - because that's exactly what the property was designed for.*

Comment: This is the solution I went with, thanks for your suggestion @Serlite. I in fact don't want the characters in my string reversed, however I'm using react and so it was trivial to reverse the characters of my string on render. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Maybe a less tricky way with text-indent and text-align:

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border:none;
  background:none;
  color:white;
  background:#26A0DA;
}
#rtl {
  text-align: right;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
label {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:2em;
  padding:0 5em;
  background:#26A0DA;
  }
```

```html
<label for="ltr">ltr
  <input id="ltr" value="*#02468456789" />
</label>

<label for="rtl">rtl
  <input id="rtl" value="*#02468456789" />
</label>
```

---

from my comment, i'll also go with a funny answer : *any feed back appreciated*

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0 2em;
  background:gray;
}
#rtl {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 900px;/* whatever */
  margin-left: -900px;/* at least as much as width to give a virtual width close to null, so it sticks at right but do not get pushed  */
}
```

```html
<label for="ltr">ltr
  <input id="ltr" value="*#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv" />
</label>

<label for="rtl">rtl
  <br/>
  <input id="rtl" value="*#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv" />
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8zbzy4sL/7/

Comment: Why you create `input`? @joshfarrant need to `div` that contain static text.

Comment: @Mohammad input are from the fiddle the OP linked , i used the op HTML. this technique works with any other imbricated tag, it worked even with IE5.5 ... long long ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:right` and `text-align:right` in `input`

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#rtl, label:last-of-type {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<label for="ltr">ltr
  <input id="ltr" value="*#02468" />
</label>
<hr />
<label for="rtl">rtl
  <input id="rtl" value="*#02468" />
</label>
```

Comment: Why you create input? He need to div that contain static text.

Comment: @Mohammad did you check OP's fiddle? OP has `input`

Comment: In comment @joshfarrant sayed: `div with static content`.

Comment: @dippas , did you use my comment to  undelete and update your answer :p

Comment: @GCyrillus no I didn't ;) actually I deleted because I found a possible dupe and my first answer wasn't working, still I keep working on it... but TBH I didn't look at the comments in the question

Comment: nevermind, it was also on your duplicate link, just the safe negative margin was not there :)  why this downvote by the way , it works ?

Comment: wonder why I was dowvoted, care to explain downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `position` to do this work. For your purpose you need to create two `div`. Parent div and child div. Child div contain text and has `ltr` direction.

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: #26A0DA;
}

.parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;   
    overflow: hidden; 
}
  
.child {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would this work with input ?

Comment: No, only for static text.